# Wordpress comments section on pages not appearing

Tags: pages

I have been using wordpress for some time now. Recently, I tried to add comments to my pages but it did not work. I went to the pages>edit page>screen options>clicked discussion and comments>selected allow comments at the bottom>update, but it did not work. I am not sure if this has to do with the code(I am not an expert coder) or if this is a system problem, but I just want to add comments to my pages. Thanks.

`and`

if ( post_password_required(  ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

Comment: Please provide us with the code of your template file. This issue can be caused by dozens of reasons and we can not help you without a code/error log.

Comment: Hi Sasan J., thanks for the response. Are you asking for the code of the page? In the page editor next to visual, it says text which contains the code for that page. Is that what you need to see?

Comment: Hello, in the admin panel go to Appearance > Editor and then select `single.php` from the right side. You can copy the code associated with the comments from there. Also if there is a `comments.php` in the right side, you might want to add that code to your question too, since we need to see what code is generating the comments. However i noticed that you mentioned **Page** in the question's title. If you mean you the single pages not posts, you must search for the proper page template instead of `single.php`.

Comment: Hi, just like to start off with thanks for your cooperation. My site has a posts page and a regular page. I want to add the comments to the page not post to clarify.                                                                                                             Single.php template:<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package BoldGrid
 */

?>

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/content-single', get_post_type() );?>

Comment: Comments.php template:<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form.
 *
 * @package BoldGrid
 */

if ( post_password_required(  ) ) {
 return;
}
?>
<section id="comments" class="comments">
 <?php do_action( 'boldgrid_comments_before' ) ?>
 <?php do_action( 'boldgrid_comments' ) ?>
 <?php do_action( 'boldgrid_comments_after' ) ?>
</section>

Comment: After pasting, I noticed that it did not appear in standard code format. I hope this does not cause difficulty for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the code but it's not readable in comments. please hit the `edit` button below your question and add it there in the code formet using ` and `.

Comment: Hi Sasan J. I followed your instructions and placed the code in my original question, but the entire code does not appear. I was not sure where to place the `and`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check discussion is enable in settings. Go to `Settings-> Discussion` and check `Default article settings->Allow people to post comments on new articles`